# FreeTDS problem connecting to SQL Server on Mac (Unexpected EOF from the server)

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, freetds

I have setup FreeTDS to connect to SQL Server database.  When I try to open TSQL in terminal on Mac (lion) I get this error:

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20017 (severity 9):
    Unexpected EOF from the server
    OS error 36, "Operation now in progress"
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

Does anybody have a clue what could be causing this?

Comment: having the exact same issue here, attempting to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 server, hosted on a Win 2008 SP2 64 bit server, from lion with tsql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make this permenant I found I need to edit the `freetds.conf` file and set it globally in there

```
vim /usr/local/freetds/etc/freetds.conf
```

`tds version = 8.0`

running `tsql -C` still showed that the version was 5.0 but connecting now worked every time.

Comment: Yep, the version 5.0 in the tsql -C definitely threw me off, but changing the tds version to 8.0 fixed this error.

Comment: In my case the file was in `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`.

Comment: Connection works with 7.3 with  all versions including Azure.  You're not supposed to use 8.0 anymore: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

Answer (score 12):

I think I got it, it's the TDS configured version, I had 5.0, which caused the error

Try running `tsql -C` to check what version are you using, and then you can invoke `tsql` overriding the version with:

`TDSVER=7.0 tsql -H hostname -p port -U domain\\\username -P password`

and it worked!

Answer (score 8):

TDS version need to match the correct tds protocol to connect to your db server, see below -

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

Choosing a TDS protocol version

```
***DB SERVER        |    TDS VERSION ***    
Microsoft SQL Server 6.x    = 4.2       
Sybase System 10 and above  = 5.0       
Sybase System SQL Anywhere  = 5.0     
Microsoft SQL Server 7.0    = 7.0       
Microsoft SQL Server 2000   = 7.1       
Microsoft SQL Server 2005   = 7.2   
Microsoft SQL Server 2008   = 7.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Also missing symlink on `libtdsodbc.so` in `/usr/lib/odbc` (for me)

```
sudo ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so libtdsodbc.so
```

should help

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  In my situation, the username for the Microsoft SQL Server database was in the form, `DOMAIN\userid`.  However, when I typed it on the command line, I think it was interpreting the slash as an escape character.  When I tried putting the slash the other direction, it still failed.  Finally, I tried putting two slashes in the original direction and it worked.  Thus the following worked for me:

```
tsql -S myhost -U DOMAIN\\userid
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. Then I did the following, and the error went away:

1. `pip install pyodbc`
2. Previously, I had used quotes for the DB server, username, and pwd in the TSQL command. This time, I **removed the quotes**.