# How do I install MySQL PHP drivers with a server running on Azure?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, azure

I'm trying to connect to a database that's hosted on Microsoft Azure and I'm getting this message:

Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find drive...

I know I'm missing a driver somewhere, but don't know where or how I'm supposed to install it. I'm not sure if I need to activate it somewhere in Azure or if this needs to be a local install.

Any info on what I'm supposed to do would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this thread could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384582/pdo-exception-error-while-connecting-to-microsoft-azure

Comment: Did you read and insure you have the relevant installation of the [mysql driver for your server OS and version from this page](http://php.net/manual/fa/mysql.installation.php)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Azure Database for MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/), you need to have a module called `pdo_mysql` which has been enabled in Azure App Service.

[image]

In your local, go to your `php.ini` file and uncomment (remove `;`) this line

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

and then restart your server.

Answer (score -1):

Please read the Prerequisites section of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-php) article to know which driver you need to install to be able to connect to a SQL Server VM on Azure or to connect to a SQL Azure Database Server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: According to the tags on the question, the problem is connecting to a mysql server on azure which looks like any other mysql server from the php/PDO side of it.

Comment: question is about MySQL, not Microsoft SQL