# SQL Server PDO could not find driver

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, pdo

I'm using Microsoft Azure SQL for my database and I'm trying to connect it to my project on my localhost using XAMPP. When I try to connect to the database using the connect string they provided:

```
    try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = tcp:app.database.windows.net,1433; Database = mydatabase", "{myusername}", "{your_password_here}");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print("Error connecting to SQL Server.");
    die(print_r($e));
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error connecting to SQL Server.PDOException Object ( [message:protected] => could not find driver
```

The error is longer but I think it's related to the driver mentioned at the end. I'm using a mac so any driver I need to install would need to be compatible with it. Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql` tag for SQL-Server questions.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database is built on the Microsoft SQL Server engine. So you might consider using **[pdo-dblib](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)** to connect to SQL Server using the PDO on a Mac. You can check out [a Stack Overflow question about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371281/how-can-i-connect-to-sql-server-from-a-mac-with-php-pdo) or refer to [this setup documentation](https://github.com/BellevueCollege/public-docs/blob/master/PHP/configure-mssql-pdodblib-mac.md).

After the driver having been installed, Azure SQL won’t actually accept connection from your local yet. And you might get the following error:

> Client with IP address '167.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to access the
>   server.

That’s because there is a firewall in the way by default. To enable access, go to the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com), click on **All Resources**, select your SQL service, click on **Firewall** in the SETTING menu.

[image]

Your client address is conveniently included in the list, so you can just click on **Add client IP** followed by **Save**.

Well, when you run your code now, it should connect.